# Verilog Syntax Error, I can't find the cause?

Tags: verilog

I am just starting out in Verilog, and can't seem to find the error in the code below, thank you in advance!

```
    module sortTwo(input logic signed [15:0] A[1:0],
            output logic signed [15:0] B[1:0]);
      always @* begin
          if (A[0]>A[1])
            begin
            assign B[1] = A[0];
            assign B[0] = A[1];
            end
        else 
            begin
            assign B[1] =A [1];
            assign B[0] = A[0];
            end
        end
    endmodule //end sortTwo
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the error is exactly?

Comment: Yeah of course, When I compile my file (sortTwo) using 
"iverilog -o sortEight sortEight.sv", then it outputs:

"sortEight.sv:1: syntax error
I give up."

Comment: Great. You can edit this into your question. This will highly improve the chance of an answer. I am no expert on Verilog, but the information you provided will enable other skilled users to help you much better.

Answer (score 2):

IcarusVerilog does not support most of SystemVerilog, and may require a switch to enable what it does support. `logic` is a SystemVerilog keyword. Try adding -g2012

Comment: FYI: The code does if you remove the `assign` keyword from the always block with Icarus Verilog using the `-g2012` argument. I tested it on [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/) which supports "Icarus Verilog 0.10.0 11/23/14", SystemVerilog is not supported in 0.9.*. Be aware that SystemVerilog support is limited in the current version of Icaraus.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use assign in always blocks. To fix your problem you need replace `assign B[1] = A[0];` to `B[1] = A[0];`

Comment: `assign` can be used in `always` block, this is what called as [procedural continuous assignments](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00037.htm). The only limitation is, both bit-select and part-select cannot be used simultaneously.

Comment: Procedural continuous assignments are not recommend as they are scheduled for deprecation (IEEE1800-2005 § 25.3 or [IEEE1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) § C.4.2). IEEE1364 (Verilog) was merged into IEEE1800 (SystemVerilog) in 2009